# How to convert a polymorphic data type to a single list of elements

Tags: haskell

I was wandering if it's possible to essentially convert a tuple which as its first element stores the number of occurrences of the second element into a single list of elements, for example:

```
[(2,'a'),(1,'b'),(4,'c')] ~> ['a','a','b','c','c','c','c']
```

The definition for such a datatype is `[(Int, a)]` (I chose `a` to be a char in this example).

Comment: Hint: use `replicate`.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I suggest you break this into smaller pieces. First, write a function `f :: (Int, a) -> [a]` which does this for just a single tuple. Once you get that to work, then it will be easier to do it for an entire list of tuples.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried concatMap?

Example list:

```
ls = [(2,True),(1,False),(4,True)]

concatMap (\tp -> replicate (fst tp) (snd tp)) ls
```

You map the function and then flat it so you got the final list:

```
=> [True,True,False,True,True,True,True]
```

Comment: The first argument to `concatMap` can also be spelled `uncurry replicate`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're learning the very basics and are supposed to be building the basic functions yourself, there are two parts to this problem:

1. Handle each of the tuples, one after the other.
2. Handle just one tuple (*e*.*g*., `(2, 'a')`) properly.

You can break it into two functions. The one that handles all of the tuples would call the one that handles just one tuple for each tuple that it gets.

Try to solve it on your own first, but if you get stuck, the following is a spoiler for the basic structure of the code (including the base and recursive case patterns for the two functions), but it isn't the finished code itself:

> ```hs
> repeatElements :: [(Int, a)] -> -- insert result type
> repeatElements []          = -- insert result for empty list base case
> repeatElements ((n, x):xs) = repeatAnElement n x -- insert part that recurses
>   where
>     repeatAnElement :: Int -> a -> -- insert result type
>     repeatAnElement 0 ch = -- insert result for zero-needed base case
>     repeatAnElement n ch = -- insert result for recursive case
> ```